# Looking for solution to search multiple online PDF's at once

Tags: java, html, pdf, adobe

At my company we have 6 separate seating chart PDF's for all employees. These PDF's are hosted online. When you need to find where a user sits, we have to search through all 6. Is there a way to search for a user's name on all these hosted documents at once? Below are things I've tried

- Website that pulls all 6 charts onto a single page using 6 iFrame tags.
- Making a custom google search bar to search all 6 sites.

Both of these solutions did not work. I believe it's because when you host a PDF online, the actual document is stored within Adobe's toolbar. I know some Java, VBA, and web design, but I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to download the PDFs to your computer, install Adobe Reader and use the Advanced PDF search. Found it here with a Google search:
https://wikispaces.psu.edu/display/training/Search+for+Text+in+Multiple+PDFs+with+Adobe+Reader

How large are these PDF records, as in how many names? If this is a common problem and there are a hefty amount, entering the records into a company database would make it the easiest moving forward. Even putting the records into a personal database could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search a folder, press `Shift+Ctrl+F` to open the Search panel.

See my solution here:
[How to search multiple PDF's in a folder at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909414/search-multiple-pdfs-in-a-folder-at-once)