# How to search multiple PDF's in a folder

Tags: acrobat

Using Adobe Acrobat Reader how do I search multiple PDF's in a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Adobe Acrobat reader:

Press Shift+Ctrl+F to open the Search panel.

Select the All PDF Documents in option.

Click the dropdown list arrow to show all drives.

Find the folder you want to search.

Enter the text you want to search for.

Click OK.

You will see the results box. Expand the nodes to see the details.